# The file name you submitted already exists on the server

Tags: codeigniter

Most of the time I upload an image I get an error which says "The file name you submitted already exists on the server". I am using codeigniter version 2.1.0.
Please help regarding how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please enable `encrypt_name`, find more [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

By this line you are telling codeigniter to create (pseudo) random filname for your file therefore your file is going to be unique (in name matter).

Furthermore you can create such a system that uploads files in folders, consider following folder structure:

```
/files/pictures/<date_of_upload>/<random_string>_big.jpg
/files/pictures/<date_of_upload>/<random_string>_thumb.jpg
```